Advice for keeping a Crawlspace functional and in good to fair condition (due to limited funds)
Hey first off thanks for helping with advice l've never owned a home with a crawlspace before this July. Little background, home is worth $110,000 paid market value. It's not a forever home so l'm only looking to put in money that will keep the house safe and functional. Live in Michigan high humidity cold winters. House was built 1957, 720 sq feet, has unfinished vented crawlspace. HAVC runs in crawl space, water lines run in attic. Water does enter the crawl space mainly near the entry fixing that now. Also financing to fix a cracked support beam with sister beams and jacks. Will add a sump pump in a low spot with help of experienced family and friends. Besides full encapsulation (quoted $13k-$20k includes dehumidifier/ opening vent in
HAVC, electrical for pump, and installation) is there anything I can do while keeping the crawlspace vented (at least during the summer) that can help condensation from the HVAC ducts with AC or in the winter if condensation occurs near rim joist near the exterior walls due to the due point? Also worried about the stack effect causing more drafts in the winter. I'm not sure if insulation around the duct work will help or cause harm due to the high humidity allowing mold growth on the insulation around the duct work.. advice is greatly appreciated

What is the condition of the floor?

Plain vents on opposite walls.  Water pipes in the attic and crawlspace(not heated) in Michigan does not sound like the best of ideas in winter.  If pipes cannot be moved to heated spaces, then heavy(R-60 plus) insulation over the pipes and maybe ceiling vents to let warm air up near the pipes will help.

Insulating the outside walls of the crawlspace will help.  This can be DIY.  Having professionals for the crack beam is good, but most of the labour can be done yourself if the contractor agrees.  They do the design and check your work.  Labour can be half or more of a contract.
